# generate circle for each line of CSV D3.js

Tags: d3.js, geometry, label

I'm trying to read in a CSV and generate a circle for each line using d3.js.

[I'd prefer not to use a callback function but that's a different question.]

I'm able to create a table for each line of data following: http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/

but I can't seem to generate a circle for each line:

```
d3.text("test.csv", function(datasetText) {

var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);

var sampleSVG2 = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100);

sampleSVG2.selectall("circle")
    .data(parsedCSV)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "blue")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not "correct" but it works. By calling a new svg area for each row and each circle it worked.

```
var sampleSVG = d3.select("#potato")
        .data(parsedCSV)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100);

sampleSVG.append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .attr("r", 40)
        .attr("cx", 50)
        .attr("cy", 50)
        .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "steelblue");});
```